# Forms based authentication not working between .Net 2.0 and .Net 4.0 application

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication

I have several web applications running on an Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6.0.

The applications are running under Asp.net 2.0.

Recently I have installed a MVC 3 Web application which is in it's nature asp.net 4 based. The forms ticket is not recocnized in this new application.

I have the same machineKey settings in the machine.config files of the different asp.net versions that have been created using this link: http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

The configuration in the login web application is like this:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".WEBAUTH"
         loginUrl="login.aspx"
         protection="None"
         slidingExpiration="true"
         enableCrossAppRedirects="false"     
         timeout="43200"     
         path="/" />
  </authentication>
```

And accordingly the configuration of the mvc app is:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".WEBAUTH"
         loginUrl="http://path2theloginapp/login.aspx"
         protection="None"
         slidingExpiration="true"
         enableCrossAppRedirects="false"     
         timeout="43200"     
         path="/" />
  </authentication>

  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
```

The login works, but the mvc application always redirects back to the login page.

Now if i change the asp.net Version of the login web application in IIS configuration to asp.net 4.0, it works. But then all the other applications running on asp.net 2 no more works.

Has anybody solved formsbased authentication in a similar situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to go the long way and opened a support case with Microsoft.

As it turned out, the relevant security updates from Microsoft Security Bulletin MS11-100 were missing:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms11-100.
Choose your operatingsystem and install the updates for .Net 2.0 and 4.0.

This updates fixed forms-based authentication without reconfiguration of the involved web applications.

Answer (score 2):

It's one of the [breaking changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770148) in ASP.NET 4.0:

> Default Hashing Algorithm Is Now HMACSHA256
>
> ASP.NET uses both encryption and hashing algorithms to help secure
>   data such as forms authentication cookies and view state. By default,
>   ASP.NET 4 now uses the HMACSHA256 algorithm for hash operations on
>   cookies and view state. Earlier versions of ASP.NET used the older
>   HMACSHA1 algorithm.
>
> Your applications might be affected if you run mixed ASP.NET
>   2.0/ASP.NET 4 environments where data such as forms authentication cookies must work across.NET Framework versions. To configure an
>   ASP.NET 4 Web application to use the older HMACSHA1 algorithm, add the
>   following setting in the Web.config file:
>
> `<machineKey validation="SHA1" />`

Comment: The validation is set as you recommended in the machine.config. Could it work, if I let the web application & application pool run under asp.net 2.0 mode?

Comment: @MS007, no, you cannot have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application run under the CLR 2.0. It requires .NET 4.0. On the other hand you could make your legacy application run under .NET 4.0.