# ASP.NET shared machineKey across .NET 3.5 and .NET 4 applications

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, machinekey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forms based authentication not working between .Net 2.0 and .Net 4.0 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295798/forms-based-authentication-not-working-between-net-2-0-and-net-4-0-application)

I have two ASP.NET applications. The first is a .NET 3.5 application and the second is a .NET 4 application.

The .NET 3.5 application is responsible for authenticating users.

They both share the same machine key, with SHA1 specified as the validation algorithm (as instructed by http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770148)

```
<machineKey decryption="Auto" decryptionKey="FD6F049F1F1E91CC29576A2B5E2197C792EB28557D016E8C" validation="SHA1" validationKey="7A057944F91ABB19DDDE99425ECE9BF79F364492A2D1F555D9A46A703F5CB0B0ADAD955D05EBAF1B65C596B572BC6EE17FA8765885E74B8C22C0396B5E042201" />
```

However I cannot login to the second application.

If I convert the first application to .NET 4 or the second to .NET 3.5, I can login. Unfortunately this is not possible in my production application.

Am I missing anything here?

Thanks,
Ben

**Update**

It would appear that the length of the cookie is shorter when created by a .NET 3.5 application. This may be a red herring but I thought I would post it for completeness.

**Update 2**

This question has been asked and answered [Forms based authentication not working between .Net 2.0 and .Net 4.0 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295798/forms-based-authentication-not-working-between-net-2-0-and-net-4-0-application).

Comment: You should now regard that machine key totally insecure as anyone can read it here. You'd better generate a new key.

Comment: Thanks, although it was just an example!